# Is the total space of Fiber bundle bordant to 0 if the fiber is null bordant?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Assume F is null bordant. Does it imply that the total space of fiber bundle 
$F\hookrightarrow E\to M$
is null bordant?

in particular what if $F$ is sphere?

Comment: In the smooth category the answer is no. This is because of the existence of exotic spheres. According to Milnor, one can construct exotix $S^7$ as a fibre bundle over $S^4$ with fibre $S^3$. However, these $S^7$'s are not the boundary of any smooth $8$-manifold!

Comment: I do not think that Somnaths answer is correct; the structural group of Milnors $S^3$-bundles is $SO(4)$, hence these exotic spheres are boundaries of disc bundles. Milnors argument is that his spheres do not bound a manifold with trivial fourth Betti number.

Comment: @ Johannes - I see my mistake now. I recalled wrongly Milnor's result on exotic spheres.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There exist oriented surface bundles $E \to B$ on closed surfaces such that $E$ has nonzero signature (first found by Atiyah and Hirzebruch). Hence $E$ is not (oriented) nullbordant, even though base and fibre are nullbordant.

Textbook reference: Morita, Geometry of characteristic classes.

A lot of material on characteristic numbers of total spaces of fibre bundles is contained in Hirzebruch "Manifolds and modular forms"

Comment: Kodaira did it before Atiyah and Hirzebruch, both of whom published the results in Kodaira's festschrift.